# How to save unicode string into datastore google appengine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unicode, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working Google App Engine using Java, i receive data from form fields and save into datastore. I receive Unicode string from `HttpServletRequest` like this:

```
URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("text"),"UTF-8")
```

It returns Unicode string correctly, then i save this string into datastore

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity entity = new Entity("TextEntity");
entity.setProperty("text", URLDecoder.decode(
                req.getParameter("name"), "UTF-8"));
entity.setProperty("createdOn", new Date());
datastore.put(entity);
```

I saw as picture below:
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the text field with unreadable characters. How can I solve this problem?
Please help me out.

Comment: How did you store the data? Is it a string field? Java and App Engine should handle this properly out-of-the-box.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you are getting the parameter right? getParameter will have already decoded it, you are applying an additional URLDecode on it that should not be necessary unless you double-encoded it in the request.

Comment: i store the data simply like this:Entity textentity = new Entity("TextEntity");
  textentity.setProperty("text", URLDecoder.decode(
    req.getParameter("name"), "UTF-8"));

  textentity.setProperty("createdOn", new Date());
  datastore.put(textentity);

Comment: i debug i saw that URLDecode decode it correctly, i can see that unicode string, but put it into datastore not as desired

Comment: this parameter comes from form field, so i did not encode it, just submit this form to servlet and doPost method will get parameters and store into datastore and i already set content="text/html; charset=utf-8" in html for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with the datastore viewer of the development server. I just ran into this exact same problem, but on the production server, the values are OK.

Comment: as it turn out that is problem of development server GAE. Thanks you.